# Swift generate single UIImage out of two UIImages side by side

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiimage

I found an answer for this same question **for Objective-C** @
*[Saving two UIImages side-by-side as one combined image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995567/saving-two-uiimages-side-by-side-as-one-combined-image)* but not for Swift.

I want to combine two UIImages side-by-side to create one UIImage. Both images would be merged at the border and maintain original resolution(no screen-shots).

How can I save the two images as one image?

ImageA + ImageB = ImageC

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the idea from the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995567/saving-two-uiimages-side-by-side-as-one-combined-image) of using `UIGraphicsContext` and `UIImage.draw` to draw the 2 images side-by-side and then create a new `UIImage` from the context.

```
extension UIImage {
    func mergedSideBySide(with otherImage: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
        let mergedWidth = self.size.width + otherImage.size.width
        let mergedHeight = max(self.size.height, otherImage.size.height)
        let mergedSize = CGSize(width: mergedWidth, height: mergedHeight)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mergedSize)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mergedWidth, height: mergedHeight))
        otherImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: self.size.width, y: 0, width: mergedWidth, height: mergedHeight))
        let mergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return mergedImage
    }
}
```

Usage (assuming `leftImage` and `rightImage` are both `UIImage`s):

```
let mergedImage = leftImage.mergedSideBySide(with: rightImage)
```

Demo of the function (using SwiftUI for quicker display using previews):

```
struct Playground_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let leftImage = UIColor.blue.image(CGSize(width: 128, height: 128))
    static let rightImage = UIColor.red.image(CGSize(width: 128, height: 128))

    static let mergedImage = leftImage.mergedSideBySide(with: rightImage) ?? UIImage()

    static var previews: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Image(uiImage: leftImage)
            Image(uiImage: rightImage)
            Image(uiImage: mergedImage)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: merged result]

The `UIColor.image` function is from [Create UIImage with solid color in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48441178/4667835).